# How can i put previous and next page path data from analytics in data studio?

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I'm trying to show pages people visited before and after they reached my specified page /samba

i can see that in analytics by going behavior>site content>all pages then just typing in samba

but how do i bring that data to data studio?

the dimension "previous page path" doesn't match what i see in analytics, what page does data studio pick for that data?

Answer (score 0):

It matches almost exactly for me.

On GA I'm using

- `behavior > site content > all pages`
- `Primary Dimension = Page`
- `Secondary dimension: Previous Page Path`

Data Studio

- `Dimensions: Page, Previous Page Path`
- `Metric = Pageviews`

Can you double check that your Data Studio date range matches your GA date range?